# HtmlUnit Post form?

Tags: java, php, html, forms, htmlunit

Hey Im trying to use HtmlUnit to login a page. Login form is different from login button form. I got the login form working but the form the login button is in is

something like this

```
<form method="POST" id="login-form" class="adjacent"   
action="/accounts/login/?    force_classic_login">
```

How would I go about getting the form for this since it doesnt have a name. How would I go about doing this

```
final HtmlForm form2 =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
HtmlForm Form = htmlPage.getHtmlElementById("login-form");
```

Comment: thanks :3 was looking for something like that. new problem but ill try fixing it before I ask for help :P again, thank you